# File content to Blob string conversion

Tags: linux, rest, shell, blob, mantis

I need to create an issue with attachement in MantisBT via REST API like it's written here : 
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/29959/mantis-bug-tracker-rest-api/7Lt6zkP?version=latest#2d3878c7-4195-42f7-53b7-9cc11f7501f4

How can i transform a local text file content into a blob string ?

I'm running on Linux CentOS 7 and need to do it locally without using any browser or human interaction, just fully automated.

I made a little Python script that store the file content in a json attribute but i need to have the BLOB representation of this content.

```
import json 

reportpath = '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SimplePipeline/workspace/reports/CompilationReport.txt'

compilReportFile = open(reportpath, 'r')
compilContent = compilReportFile.read()
compilReportFile.close()

with open('/home/Jenkins/PFE/Static/newMantisRequestBody.json', 'r') as file:
     json_data = json.load(file)
     json_data["description"] = compilContent
with open('/home/Jenkins/PFE/Static/newMantisRequestBody.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2)
```

I expect to end with something like this :

```
"files": [
        {
            "name": "test.txt",
            "content": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIFRFU1QuDQpUaGlzIGlzIGEgVEVTVC4NClRoaXMgaXMgYSBURVNULg0KVGhpcyBpcyBhIFRFU1QuDQpUaGlzIGlzIGEgVEVTVC4="
        }
    ]
```

Or, now i'm only able to do this :

```
  "description": "MY FILE CONTENT STRING HERE"
```

Do you guys have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by 'blob' format. For me this looks just like base64 encoded file content - there are various tools for that conversions...

Comment: Actually, I dont' really understand the difference between a BLOB and a base64 encoded str..

Comment: a BLOB is a 'binary large object', si just the file content (as binary data), which cannot be use in json. Base64 encoding data translates this data to a string which can be sent in a json text field (see the content field in your example). you can google the rest...

Comment: Thank you very much, i found the solution !
I used Python to transform my file content into Base64 String.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i needed to transform my file content into a **Base64** String before inserting it in my Json.

See the **TMS's** comment above if you want more precisions.

Thank you again !